# Why toString() method works differently between Array and ArrayList object in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, tostring

```
    String[] array = {"a","c","b"};
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("a");
    list.add("b");
    list.add("c");
    System.out.println(array);
    System.out.println(list);
```

For `list` `[a, b, c]` is output while for `array` some address is output. When we want to output the `array` values, we can use `Arrays.toString(array);` which works just like `list`.

I just wonder why we can't call `toString()` directly on `array` to get the values. Isn't it more intuitive and convenient to do so? What results in the different treatments on `Array` and `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The main difference between an array and an arraylist is that an arraylist is a class that is written in Java and has its own implementation (including the decision to override `toString`) whereas arrays are part of the language specification itself. In particular, the [JLS 10.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7) states:

> The members of an array type are all of the following:
>
> - The public final field length
> - The public method clone, which overrides the method of the same name in class Object and throws no checked exceptions.
> - All the members inherited from class Object; the only method of Object that is not inherited is its clone method.

In other words the language specification prevents the `toString` method of an array to be overriden and it therefore uses the default implementation defined in `Object` which prints the class name and hashcode.

Why this decision has been made is a question that should probably be asked to the designers of the language...

Answer (score 4):

> I just wonder why we can't call toString() directly on array to get
>   the values.

Actually `toString` method is called on the array object. But, since array type does not override `toString` method from `Object` class, so default implementation of `toString` is invoked, that returns the representation of the form that you see.

The representation is of the form: -

```
[typeOfArray@hashCode
```

In your case it's something like: -

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@3e25a5
```

Whereas, in case of `ArrayList` instances, the overriden `toString` method in `ArrayList` class is invoked.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is because toString is defined in a few different places, with different behaviours.

The Arrays class defines toString as a static method, to be invoked like

```
Arrays.toString(arr_name);
```

But the Arrays class also inherits the non-static method toString from the Object class.  So if called on an instance, it invokes Object.toString which returns a string representation of the object (eg: [Ljava.lang.Object;@4e44ac6a)

So Arrays.toString() and MyObject.toString() are calling different methods with the same name.

The ArrayList class inherits toString from the AbstractCollection class, where it is a non static method, so can be called on the object like:

```
MyArrayList.toString();
```

Because it's a string representation of a collection and not an object, the result is the values in a readable format like [one, two].

Answer (score 0):

Because when you print `toString()`, it will by default print `className@HashCode`.

So, when you print `array`  then above will be printed.

But `ArrayList` is extened by `AbstractCollection` class and where the `toString()` method is overriden as below

```
 public String toString() {
        Iterator<E> it = iterator();
        if (! it.hasNext())
            return "[]";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append('[');
        for (;;) {
            E e = it.next();
            sb.append(e == this ? "(this Collection)" : e);
            if (! it.hasNext())
                return sb.append(']').toString();
            sb.append(',').append(' ');
        }
    }
```

which prints the readable format of the `ArrayList` object.

Answer (score 0):

This is the toString method call for ArrayList. But for Arrays you cant find such.

```
 /**
 * Returns a string representation of this collection.  The string
 * representation consists of a list of the collection's elements in the
 * order they are returned by its iterator, enclosed in square brackets
 * (<tt>"[]"</tt>).  Adjacent elements are separated by the characters
 * <tt>", "</tt> (comma and space).  Elements are converted to strings as
 * by {@link String#valueOf(Object)}.
 *
 * @return a string representation of this collection
 */
public String toString() {
    Iterator<E> it = iterator();
    if (! it.hasNext())
        return "[]";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append('[');
    for (;;) {
        E e = it.next();
        sb.append(e == this ? "(this Collection)" : e);
        if (! it.hasNext())
            return sb.append(']').toString();
        sb.append(',').append(' ');
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For `array` **toString()** method it prints the memory address. But in  `ArrayList` this class overrides `Object` **toString()** method .

**toString() implementation of ArrayList**

```
   public String toString() {
    Iterator<E> i = iterator();
    if (! i.hasNext())
        return "[]";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append('[');
    for (;;) {
        E e = i.next();
        sb.append(e == this ? "(this Collection)" : e);
        if (! i.hasNext())
        return sb.append(']').toString();
        sb.append(", ");
    }
}
```