# Not able to sort integer list in ascending order

Tags: java

I have integer list from json file, and printing that complete list. After sorting that list it is printing in a different manner

```
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(keys);
    System.out.println("list is :" + list);
    Collections.sort(list);
    System.out.println("after sorting is:"+list);
```

o/p list :

```
[338, 339, 332, 333, 159, 330, 158, 331, 157, 336, 156, 337, 155,etc...0,1,14]
```

instead of sorting in `0,1,2` etc...way it got sorted in below manner:

after sorting is:

```
[0, 1, 10, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105,etc..]
```

code:

```
response = httpUtil.getResponse(aperture_url);
parser = new JSONParser();
object = parser.parse(((String) response));
jsonObject = (JSONObject) object;
aperture_details = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("response");
historic_price = (JSONObject) aperture_details.get("historic_price");
System.out.println("historic_price:" + historic_price);
keys = historic_price.keySet();
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(keys);
System.out.println("list is :" + list);
Collections.sort(list);
System.out.println("after sorting is:"+list);
```

Comment: is there a 2 in the original list?

Comment: Isn't 0, 1, 10, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105 ....ascending order?

Comment: yes there is 2 in the original list

Comment: Yes that is ascending order. If you want to sort in descending order you'll have to write your own `Comparator` and pass that in as well in the `Collections.sort` function, or you could call the `Collections.reverseOrder`

Comment: Yohannes..when 2,3,4 and all are available from 0-732, why it should print in that way?

Comment: To clarify OP's point, I believe they mean that it is sorting more like a `List<String>` might sort. `0,1,10,11,2,21,22,3`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - I'm finding the behaviour here hard to believe without reproducing it myself.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error, at least when the list elements are indeed `Integer`s, as the list's type parameter indicates.  If you present a [mcve] demonstrating the problem then I suspect we will be able to tell you that your elements are *not*, in fact, `Integer`s, but rather `String`s, and that you have turned off or are ignoring type safety warnings from your compiler.

Comment: I am taking this list from a json file, how can present the example here?

Comment: @qatest use hard-coded data instead.  `list = {1, 100, 2};`  Or `null` it.  Or load the json from a shorter hard-coded string.

Comment: Well first, you should start by showing the actual code.  An `ArrayList` when asked for its `toString()` method will present a memory address along with the class type `ArrayList`.  This tells me that both of your lines that include `System.out.println()` are not part of the code that you are running.

Comment: response = httpUtil.getResponse(aperture_url);
  parser = new JSONParser();
  object = parser.parse(((String) response));
  jsonObject = (JSONObject) object;
  aperture_details = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("response");
  
  historic_price = (JSONObject) aperture_details.get("historic_price");
  // System.out.println("historic_price:" + historic_price);

  keys = historic_price.keySet();
  

  List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(keys);
  
  System.out.println("list is :" + list);
  Collections.sort(list);
  System.out.println("after sorting is:"+list);

Comment: @qatest Please put the code in the original question by editing it instead of comment.  (lower left grey `edit` link)

Comment: weird, your example shows alphabetical sort order, but a `ArrayList<Integer>` is by default sorted after the numeric value (like you expect), so something is wrong with your code example!?

Comment: Am I mistaken? I think `JSONObject.keySet()` returns `Set<String>`, so this should be the type of your `keys`, and you should not be able to do `new ArrayList<Integer>(keys)` (not without going through raw types, which you should avoid for your own good). Anyway, the reason why your numbers seem to be sorted as strings may be lying here…

Comment: Set<Integer> keys = new HashSet<>();

Comment: this is how I declared keys

Comment: What is the return type of the `JSONObject.keySet()` you are using?

Comment: numbers- integer

Comment: I am repeating Jon and John: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please. There’s nothing we can do to help you with the code snippets we have now.

Comment: I can not reproduce your result in any way... `Set<Integer> keys = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(5,2,3,25,10,7,4));
  List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(keys);
    System.out.println("list is :" + list);
    Collections.sort(list);
    System.out.println("after sorting is:"+list);` prints `list is :[2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 25, 10]
after sorting is:[2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10, 25]` (HashSet pre sorts some numbers)

Comment: what baffles me a little, why would `JSONObject.keySet()` return a `Set<Integer>` in the first place, since keys can be alphanumeric it should be `Set<String>`!? some research `public interface JsonObject
extends JsonStructure, Map<String,JsonValue>` so the KeySet should be of typwe String like the keys of the Map

Comment: @xander: My *guess* is that the OP is casting to `Set<Integer>` and ignoring the warning - at which point it all makes sense.

Comment: @ebyrob: It's not really clear from just that description what you're looking for. An actual cast will just provide the exact same object - it's not clear whether you want that, or something that checks, etc. But I'd suggest asking a new question if nothing on SO satisfies you.

Comment: @ebyrob: Something like `(Set<Integer>) (Set) keys` would do it. Or just `keys` being typed as `Set` to start with. But as we can see now, it's not quite that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide your definition of the variable `keys`!!

You said you get it from a JSON file, so I suppose you use something like `JSON.parse(...content of your file here...)`

If so, keys should be an Array.

give it a try by changing
`List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(keys);`
to
`List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(keys));`

Comment: Set<Integer> keys = new HashSet<>(); -- this is keys

Comment: I'm getting this error for the above: The constructor ArrayList<Integer>(List<Set<Integer>>) is undefined

Comment: Your getting this error, because my guess that `keys` is an Array was false.
With `keys` as `Set<Integer>`, try `keys.toString()` instead of `Arrays.asList(keys))`.

IMPORTANT: for that you have use `new ArraList<>` or `new ArraList<Object>` instead of `new ArrayList<Integer>`

Comment: can u give one example?

Comment: @JohannesGriebenow what's the point of that? see my example in the comment on the question, for me my HashSet<Integer> gets sorted in the ArrayList.. I've no clue what OP is doing maybe some old compiler cache problem who knows

Comment: @xander The point is, that `Collections.sort()` implements natural ordering, this could create problems with Type `List<Set<T>>` because it is designed for `List<T>`.
found here: [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)

`.toString` could fix this, like here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780374/why-tostring-method-works-differently-between-array-and-arraylist-object-in-ja)

because the result doesn't print the real values of `keys` according to @qa_test comments on the original question.

Comment: but it's not `List<Set<T>>`, `new ArrayList<T>(Collection<T> c)` just copies the elements of the container to the list, it's not adding the whole set as an element AFAIK

Comment: @xander I suggested `new ArrayList<Set<T>>(Collection<T>)` just copies the elements and `ArrayList<T>(Collection<T>)` adds the whole Set as an element.
But of course I could be wrong, should be tested.

Comment: @JohannesGriebenow from the official doc: `public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)
Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified collection, in the order they are returned by the collection's iterator.` just to clarify that, I'm not sure if we ever figure out the real problem here :D