# Unable to print an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have some code that pulls a data set from a database. I can Println each element, so I know it is coming out of the database fine.

if I do this:

```
  public ArrayList<String[]> selectsingle(String query) throws SQLException{
    ArrayList <String[]> result = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    connect();
    stat = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(query);
    int columnCount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
    while(rs.next()){
      String[] row = new String[columnCount];
      for (int i=0; i <columnCount ; i++){
        row[i] = rs.getString(i + 1);
        System.out.println(row[i]);    
      }
      result.add(row);
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
    }
    disconnect();
    return result;

  }
```

then the `println` at the end gives me my array and each element.

The problem comes when I want to pass the Array back to the calling function, I am only getting the memory location, and I cannot `println` the elements at all. I cannot for the life of me figure out where I am going wrong, as it seems to be the result.add that is throwing me off!

The code that calls this:

```
 private void TableCustMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       
    try {
        ArrayList<String[]> result = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        result = db.selectsingle("SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE ID = " + TableCust.getValueAt(TableCust.getSelectedRow(), 0));
        System.out.println(result.toArray());
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(panelCustMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

and no matter what I do with the result, I always get this:

3 - element
Mr - element
Rob - element
Man - element
[3, Mr, Rob, Man] - the println(row) (as expected)
[Ljava.lang.Object;@502f737f - the println(result.toArray()) after adding and returning the row to the result array.

Comment: Can you show us the code that is allegedly not printing the elements properly?

Comment: "I am only getting the memory location," suggests you may be seeing `Type@hexHashCode`, but this is strange since you used in your code `Arrays.toString(row);` which suggests you are already aware of this problem. So why not use `Arrays.toString(row);` again?

Comment: *"when I want to pass the Array back to the calling function"* Do you mean in the caller of `selectsingle`, in code you haven't shown, you have trouble printing the returned `ArrayList<String[]>`? If so, why is that confusing you, since you already seem to know that you need to use `Arrays.toString()` to correctly print an array?

Comment: It's not a memory location, it's a hashcode, but please include the output in the question to make that more clear

Comment: @Ypsilon Do not (try to) post code in a comment. Delete that comment, and edit the question to clarify it.

Comment: Do you think that `Arrays.toString(row)` is an inplace operation? Because it is not.

Comment: Also, please include the code in the calling function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like you are using the "Arrays.toString()" on the String[] array, use it inside a foreach:

```
result.forEach(strArray -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArray)));
```

**The explanation is:**

The "System.out.println()" method performed on a variable which holds a reference to an object, is actually calling object's toString() method behind scenes.

In your example String[] array is your object, but it's toString() method is not overridden but inherited from Object class (cause all arrays in java doesn't override it), thus a toString() of the Object is called which prints the class full name + @ + hashcode result. In your example String[] array's toString() print is --> "[Ljava.lang.**Object**;@502f737f". The "Object" class is printed because you used "result.toArray()", which just created array of Objects (same issue).

The only reason the inner method is successfuly printing the result is because you are calling Arrays.toString() which iterates & calls array's object's toString() method and eventually returns their String representation.

So just use it at the outer calling method as well.

more complete explanation on String[] (don't want to repeat, see "members of array type"), --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/13780418/992200

BTW, the suggested answer prints each array from the ArrayList of rows in a different line, you can print it at the same line with the efficient StringBuilder\StringBuffer\StringJoiner (pick the one you need).

Comment: This worked a treat, thank you so much. Only one question, I dont actually want to println, I want to add each element to a variable, to settext on a Textbox....?

Comment: Do you want to add each String[] row array to the Textbox ? if yes then just modify the inner lambda from my example you an replace the printing by any code u wish, for multiple lines of code wrap it with "{ }":

example:

'result.forEach(strArray -> { System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArray)));
//add your code...
}'

BTW, pls use one of the StringBuilder\StringBuffer\StringJoiner for efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate throught this arraylist in order to print each row:

```
result = db.selectsingle("SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE ID = " + TableCust.getValueAt(TableCust.getSelectedRow(), 0));
for(int i= 0;i<result.size();i++)
  System.out.println(result.get(i));
```

Comment: Used that exact code (and simlar, I tried the forEach method) and the result I get is: [Ljava.lang.String;@212538cd  Still cant get it to work!

Comment: @Rosário Pereira Fernandes:  `System.out.println(result.get(i));` calls the String[] object's toString method --> which calls Object's default method, pls see my answer :)